# Projecting Sphere to Rectangle/Square using Mercerator Projection

Tags: geometry, conformal-geometry, projection, map-projections

I am learning some projection technique where we can project a 3d object like globe to a 2d. I have the 3d coordinates of points on the surface of sphere same as globe. Here is a reference where a globe can be projected on a plane using Stereo-graphic projection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) but this projection project the globe to a circle but i am trying to project sphere to a rectangle the same way as the globe is projected on a small paper (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).

Answer (score 1):

Both Stereographic and Mercator projections map the globe to unbounded regions. However, the [Lambert cylindrical equal area projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_cylindrical_equal-area_projection) does map the entire globe to a rectangle.

[image]

Comment: I understand your point but according to the formula in the Wikipedia page it needs latitude and longitude, where phi is the latitude (phi is the angle given in spherical coordinates ) but what about lambda which is the longitude ?

Comment: You can always use $$ \begin{align} \sin(\phi)&=\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\\ \tan(\lambda/2)&=\frac{y}{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \end{align} $$

Comment: here x,y,z in the formula state by you are the Cartesian coordinate of a point on the surface of the sphere right ?

Comment: "I have the 3d coordinates of points on the surface of sphere same as globe."